# $E[g(X,Y)|Y=y] = E[g(X,y)|Y=y]$ - Exercise $3.77$ Ross Probability Models.

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation

How would you show that $E[g(X,Y)|Y=y] = E[g(X,y)|Y=y]$ in the **continuous** case? This problem is in Probability Models by Ross. No solution is provided, and no information is given about the random variables, altough I suppose we could assume the functions involved are absolute convergent or something.

The penultimate step in the discrete case is that all $p(X=i, Y=j|Y=y)$ are $0$ unless $j = y$, which I can't translate into the continuous case. My real analysis skills are non-existent, but you aren't supposed to know that for this book either way.

Comment: As long as everything is continuous, $\mathbb{E}[h(X,Y) \, \mid \, Y = y] = (\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_{X}(x,y) \, dx)^{-1} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} h(x,y) f(x,y) \, dx$.  Here $f$ is the joint density of $(X,Y)$.  If you plug in $h(x',y') = g(x',y')$ and $h(x',y') = g(x',y)$, you will get the same answer in either case.

Comment: Right, so the key is that you immediately ignore the parts where the conditional density is 0. Is there a way to to start from some more general step? I feel like we should originate from a double integral and later reach the equation you provide.

Comment: Yes, but you said your real analysis skills are non-existent. ;)

Comment: Haha, fair point! But I lied, I've read a class based on Rudin. Is that enough to understand the steps in between? If so, and if you have the time, I would very much appreciate a more detailed explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Let $\mu_{X,Y}$ be the joint law of $(X,Y)$.  This is the Borel probability measure in $\mathbb{R}^{d} \times \mathbb{R}^{d}$ (assuming $X$ and $Y$ are both random vectors taking values in $\mathbb{R}^{d}$) such that, for any two Borel sets $A, B \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{d}$,
\begin{equation*}
\mu_{X,Y}(A \times B) = \mathbb{P}\{X \in A, \, \, Y \in B\}.
\end{equation*}
Similarly, let $\mu_{Y}$ denote the law of $Y$.

It is possible to show that there is a weakly $\mu_{Y}$-measurable, probability measure-valued function $y \mapsto \mu_{y}^{X}$ such that if $f$ is a bounded, continuous function on $\mathbb{R}^{d} \times \mathbb{R}^{d}$, then
\begin{equation*}
\int_{\mathbb{R}^{d} \times \mathbb{R}^{d}} f(x,y) \, \mu_{X,Y}(dx \otimes dy) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^{d}} \left[ \int_{\mathbb{R}^{d}} f(x,y) \, \mu_{y}^{X}(dx) \right] \, \mu_{Y}(dy).
\end{equation*}
I have seen the measures $\{\mu^{X}_{y}\}_{y \in \mathbb{R}^{d}}$ referred to as a regular family of conditional probabilities --- the term disintegration is also used to describe this process of decomposing $\mu$.

One now chooses a suitable $\mu_{Y}$-measurable set $E \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{d}$ with $\mu_{Y}(E) = 1$ and defines $\mathbb{E}(\cdot \, \mid \, Y = y)$ for $y \in E$ and bounded, continuous $f : \mathbb{R}^{d} \times \mathbb{R}^{d} \to \mathbb{R}$ by the formula
\begin{equation*}
\mathbb{E}(f(X,Y) \, \mid \, Y = y) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^{d}} f(x,y) \, \mu^{X}_{y}(dx).
\end{equation*}
With this formula in hand, it is now clear that $\mathbb{E}(g(X,Y) \, \mid \, Y = y) = \mathbb{E}(g(X,y) \, \mid \, Y = y)$ for $\mu_{Y}$-a.e. $y \in \mathbb{R}^{d}$ (in particular, for $y \in E$).

Comment: +1 : the notion of regular conditional probability is important to introduce Markov processes in continuous time. It is not easy at all to see why they exist.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon, do you have a reference that stresses the role of regular conditional probabilities in the theory of continuous time Markov processes?  I've been meaning to study the continuous time case; I only ever spent time on discrete time processes.

Comment: Hi Peter, good point, I actually don't know of any such reference. I expect such a topic to be so specialized that one can only find it in papers, and even from the first few papers that I saw I wasn't convinced with what I saw.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to prove it in the simplified case g(X,Y) = XY. (Part a in Ross' book)

Let Z = XY. Then $$E[Z|Y=y] = \int z \cdot f_{Z|Y}(z|y)dz$$ $$= y \int x \cdot f_{Z|Y}(z|y)dx$$ through change of variable. And $$ f_{Z|Y}(z|y) = f_{XY|Y}(xy|y)$$ $$ = \frac{f(XY=xy, Y=y)}{f(Y=y)}$$ $$=\frac{f(X=x, Y=y)}{f(Y=y)}$$
which gives the desired conclusion in this case.

Is this any more rigorous than the comment made by Peter Morfe in the comment above? To convince ourselves about the last step, I suppose we could look at the cumulative distribution functions and take derivatives.

Comment: The last step checks out using cumulative distribution functions, as you suggested.